# How i can get the projectURL and fileName from firebase? (r package FireData)

Tags: r, firebase

Hi and thanks for reading me. Actually im triyng to get a firestore data with the package "FireData", but i have an issue with the database, because i can't find the projectURL and fileName from firebase portal, anyone know's how i can get this information?

My code for auth is the following:

```
library(fireData)
token <- anonymous_login(project_api = sys.getenv("key"))
```

and i try to get the data using the name of the firebase project, like this:

```
download(projectURL = "https://projectname.firebaseio.com/", fileName = "main/projectname")
```

For the project name im using the following:

[image]

Does anyone knows hot i can get this strings? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

`${project_name}.firebaseio.com` are usually reserved for firebase realtime database projects, which when activated, you can find the name on [this page](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/). Looking at the R package you are referencing and when it was developed, I would assume that it is referencing the firebase realtime database and not firestore.